# Reorder r dataframe columns with where column names have mixed letters and numbers

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny

I have a table similar to the following

| Subject | Day -1 | Day 1 | Day -2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 00002 | 2 | 4 | 6 |

I was wondering how I can sort the column names with "Subject" first, then Day -2, Day -1, finally Day 1 in numeric order? I have many more columns than this and may need to do this on multiple tables so would appreciate an automated answer.

Comment: Please use `dput()` and post a reproducible example so we can see exactly the structure of the column names

Comment: Using ARRANGE for column permutation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `gtools::mixedsort`:

```r
dat[c("Subject", gtools::mixedsort(names(dat)[-1]))]
```

output

```r
  Subject Day -2 Day -1 Day 1
1       1      5      1     3
2       2      6      2     4
```

---

Or in `dplyr`, with `num_range` and `relocate`:

```r
dat %>% 
  relocate(Subject, num_range("Day ", -2, 2))
```

Comment: The `dplyr` version does not work when I try. Why?

Answer (score 1):

To complete @Maël answers. We could use also `mixedorder` also from `gtools`:

Cave: by removing first column, `mixedorder` returns an index that starts with 1. So it needs to start from 2, therefore +1.

```
library(gtools)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(1, mixedorder(names(.)[-1])+1)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
  Subject `Day -2` `Day -1` `Day 1`
  <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
1 00001          5        1       3
2 00002          6        2       4
```